# Angular 2 fired action after all children view render

Tags: angular

Is it possible for the parent get notified that all the child views have been rendered?

I know that we have lifecycle hooks like `ngAfterViewChecked()` but is it fired after child views are rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation states (about `ngAfterViewChecked`):

> Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views.
>   Called after the `ngAfterViewInit` and every subsequent `ngAfterContentChecked()`.
>   A component-only hook.

So, yeah, child views will trigger this callback. The problem is that you can't tell which view was updated. If you want to know about specific views being updated I suggest to wrap them in `Components`, override `ngAfterViewChecked` inside each one and use `EventEmitter` (as `Output`) to notify parent `Component`. In case you want to listen for initial render, override `ngAfterContentChecked`.

**Update #1:**

If you care only about the *first* render and don't have to differentiate between views it's enough to override `ngAfterViewInit`:

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views. Called once after the first `ngAfterContentChecked()`. A
>   component-only hook.

Comment: No i dont need to know is there a change. i only need to know when all childs is fully rendered.

Comment: Ok, then go with ngAfterViewInit. Updated my answer.